# Conformal sets in $\Bbb C^n$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to show whether these two sets are conformally equivalent.

$\Delta_n=\{(z_1,\dots,z_n):|z_i|<1,1\le i\le n|\}$ and $\Omega=\{(z_1,\dots,z_n):\text{Im}(z_1)>0\}$ where $n\ge 2$
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff, I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff, so they should be conformal?

Comment: Did you try looking at $n=2$, say? Then it might be easier to obtain a generalization.